# Why is the speed of fully connected neural network very fast no matter how large the prediction dataset is?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

I used tensorflow(GPU and CPU) to train a 5-layers fully connected DNN with few parameters (Less than 300 parameters). And then I use it to predict two datasets with data sizes of 1000 and 1 million, respectively.  I found that not only the dataset with size of 1000 completed the prediction in 0.05 seconds, but also the dataset with size of 1 million completed the prediction in 0.05 seconds. Why?
Why can DNN predict such a huge dataset quickly?  Why does the size of the data set affect the speed of DNN so little ?

Comment: In what environment are  you running this?  Is it possible you are using a clustered computing system such as AWS where additional resources are spun up for larger problems and the work processed in parallel?

Comment: I just used a laptop, tensorflow_GPU and tensorflow_CPU processe datasets with sizes of 1 million very quickly. My model is very small (less than 20 neurons per layer) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network is simply too small to be a real computational load. As a back of the envelope calculation, if you have a modern CPU with about $3.2$GHz, then you can do $3.2*10^9$ calculations per second. Your network only has $500$ parameters, so for an input of $1000$ elements, you do in each epoch about $500*1000=5*10^5$ operations which is orders of magnitude less than what your CPU can do in one second. If you now increase your data set to $10^6$ elements, then you still only have $500*10^6 = 5*10^8$ operations.

On the other hand, if you would add more layers, then your computation time would increase drastically. For an input layer of size $m$ and output layer of size $n$, you have(without bias) $m*n$ parameters. If you repeat this a few times, then you have very easily millions of parameters.

The calculation above is of course not realistic. There is a lot more to consider to estimate the performance of a network, such as memory transfer and usage.